# Mount drive from redhat to a windows share with CIFS

Tags: networking, permissions, mount

I have been trying to mount a drive, but anything I do i get 'Access Denied',

I tried:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.x.x/m -o username=user,password=mypass /mnt/mymount
mount -t cifs //192.168.x.x/m -o credentials=cred /mnt/mymount
mount -t cifs //192.168.x.x/m -o username=user,password=mypass,domain=xxxxx /mnt/mymount
```

I want to user a local user account on the windows machine and not a domain user account. Is this possible?

I tried to put in the computer name as the domain, the fully qualified domain name, also under username I tried `computer\user`, none of those seem to work.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you checked Event Log on the Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Samba user corresponding to the Linux user whose share you are trying to mount.  Try running `smbpasswd -a user` to create a Samba password entry for user `user`.